# Focusing on a window spawned by a select_list value

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

The site I'm testing has a page that spawns a new data window when a 
specified select_list value is chosen.  To date, I've never been able 
to automate this, and I've been having this as a manual step for ages 
until I can figure it out.  Example HTML for the select_list in 
question is as such:

```
<select name="cboFoo" class="txtboxwidth left" id="cboFoo" 
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cboFoo\',\'\')', 0)" 
jQueryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX="7">
```

Considering a click_no_wait works well enough elsewhere in our site 
for javascript confirmations and suchlike, I hoped the following would 
work for a select_list; but it doesn't.  The new data window never 
appears:

```
browser.select_list(:id, "cboFoo").select_no_wait("Bar")
```

I welcome any suggestions, as this is currently the only area of our 
site I can't automate.

Thanks,

GJHmf

Comment: Please provide link to the page where we can reproduce the problem. What kind of popup are you dealing with? (The list of known popups is here: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups)

Comment: Is this actually a separate window, or some kind of a jquery utility that creates something (often a div) that just looks like a window to the user, but is really just another element in the dom.  If it's a JQuery widget can you point us at a demo page that implements it?  right now we just don't have enough to go on to assist you with this other than very general advice.

Comment: Re-tagged to hopefully get some more attention (from the original poster as well).

Answer (score 0):

Since the control is looking for an 'onchange' event, you may need to make your selection and then fire that event against that element to get the javascript to invoke.

```
browser.select_list(:id, "cboFoo").select('Bar')
browser.select_list(:id, "cboFoo").fire_event('onchange')
```

If that's not it, then please provide more info as requested in the comments to the question.